# WebDriverException on invoking webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME) through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm pretty sure this'll be a head smacker, but I've followed ever bit of doc I can find and I can't get rid of this error.  I'm in the process of setting up a Selenium Grid (in Docker) and can get tests to run only if I don't specify the remote.  Here's the code

```
def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

FWIW, this works fine, but isn't useful in a grid environment without the command_executor:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Based on a number of sources, including https://hackr.io/blog/complete-guide-selenium-webdriver, the call to the RemoteWebDriver should be correct.

Here's the error:

```
ERROR: test_hackernews_search_for_selenium (__main__.HackerNewsSearchTest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in setUp
    self.browser = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: None
```

Comment: Did you start the _Selenium Grid Hub_ and provision the _Selenium Grid Node_?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I'm not completely sure what the difference was, but I found if I created the nodes with docker-compose, everything sorted itself out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
ERROR: test_hackernews_search_for_selenium (__main__.HackerNewsSearchTest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in setUp
    self.browser = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
.
WebDriverException: Message: None
```

...implies that the *client program* was unable to initiate a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **connectivity** between the *Selenium Grid Hub* and *Selenium Grid Node*.

---

### Solution

Ensure the following:

- The *Selenium Grid Hub* is initiated successfully.
- The *Selenium Grid Node* is initiated and provisioned successfully within the *Selenium Grid Hub*

Comment: I suspect you're probably correct.  I set up the grid by hand first.  I think that docker-compose eliminated any mistake I might have made.